# Sending Content Builder emails via the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, dataextensions

Is it possible to send emails created in Marketing Cloud Content Builder through the API? I don't mind whether it is SOAP or REST.

I'd like the data source to be a filter on a Data Extension.

Comment: is it marketing cloud?

Comment: Yes its marketing cloud

Comment: If the source is a filtered data extension you could just use journey builder or automation studio rather than an API to send the email.

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is for it to be fully automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining the ETEmail in the ETEmailSendDefinition you have to specify the 'CustomerKey' and not the ID.

It appears that if you want to send a 'Classic' email the ID works, however if you're trying to send a 'Content Builder' email you need to specify the 'CustomerKey'.